# Is it a good idea to add a cover letter to a scholarship application when a cover letter is not specifically required?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, funding, cv

My scholarship application was denied yesterday. Fortunately, I can still request the scholarship committee to reconsider my application, provided that I have new credentials to present in my curriculum vitae. The scholarship application portal asks only for an updated curriculum vitae. But would it be a good idea to add a cover letter to my curriculum vitae that explains why a need the scholarship?

Answer (score 1):

If you have been already denied, then it would be good to explain how the current application differs from the application that was denied. If I were on the committee, that would be the first thing I am looking for. The best medium for this explanation depends. As a committee member, I am not likely to spend a lot of time reading long explanations. As the portal asks for an updated CV and as the request has to be based on a change in qualifications, it seems that a cover letter is usually not the best medium. However, make sure that the change in your qualification is not hidden in your CV. If it might get lost, then yes, put in a very short cover letter.